# How to avoid authentication for some url pattern?

Tags: java, spring-boot

> I want "/api/user/**" should not required any authentication, user can direct access to this url in my spring boot app.
>
> Below is my SecurityConfig class

```
public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity
                .cors(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .authorizeHttpRequests(requests-> requests
                        .requestMatchers("/api/user/**").permitAll()
                        .anyRequest().authenticated()
                )
                .formLogin((form)-> form
                        .loginPage("/login")
                        .loginProcessingUrl("/login")
                        .defaultSuccessUrl("/welcome")
                        .permitAll()
                )
                .logout((logout)-> logout
                        .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
                        .permitAll()
                );
        return httpSecurity.build();

    }
```

when i hit "api/user/**" it redirect me to "api/login"